# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'BuildContext'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, phpmyadmin

[image: this the exception i got , there is no particular error show in the code,]

> void pop([Object? object]) {
> if (Navigator.canPop(getContext))
> Navigator.pop(getContext, object);`**in getContext the exception is thrown . is it about the backend?

in other system its looks fine , no exception find, so I could not understand what is problem  happens in my system **`
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `context` instead of `getContext()` and context is the build context which you can access in the stateful class

```
Navigator.pop(context);
```

Reference https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics

Comment: its just a dart file thats why i use getContext, there is no statefull class

Comment: Then you can pass the context in the method and use it